# An Original Source Containing the Sermon of St. Leonard of Port Maurice: The Little Number of Those Who are Saved

Tags: catholicism, soteriology, eschatology, saint, sermon

This rather famous homily of the eighteenth century Franciscan is rather easy to come by on the internet; for example, see

https://www.saintsbooks.net/books/St.%20Leonard%20of%20Port%20Maurice%20-%20The%20Little%20Number%20of%20Those%20Who%20Are%20Saved.pdf

However, I have not been able to find a book from which this sermon was extracted; nor, have any of those that have posted this indicated the "ancient" source from which the sermon (now presented in modern English is derived.)

After the end of the sermon, the above link, for example, indicates "This sermon by Saint Leonard of Port Maurice was preached during the reign of Pope Benedict XIV, who so loved the great missionary."

QUESTION: Can anyone cite an original source (an archived old book, perhaps) which contains this sermon of St. Leonard of Port Maurice?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the article "[Who Are Saved?](https://catholicmagazine.news/who-are-saved/)" on [catholicmagazine.news](https://catholicmagazine.news/) (near the bottom of the page), the aforesaid sermon can be found in:

"Prediche quaresmali". Assisi: Ottavio Sgariglia, 1806, v. III, pp. 146-182.

Some of the other Volumes of this work can be found on Internet Archive, but I was not able to locate Volume III there. Nevertheless, if one goes to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/books?id=4Mj7D_Cvsg4C&pg=PA1&lpg=PA1&dq=volume+III+Prediche+quaresimali+del+B.+Leonardo+da+Porto+Maurizio+Minore+Riformato+e+Missionario+Apostolico+del+Ritiro+di+San+Bonaventura+in+Roma,&source=bl&ots=dG1JWw23_B&sig=ACfU3U2y6qLucD3sW7saeQhTqZM_tfBHCg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiFh6XpgN76AhWfM1kFHWrzDgQQ6AF6BAgXEAM#v=onepage&q=volume%20III%20Prediche%20quaresimali%20del%20B.%20Leonardo%20da%20Porto%20Maurizio%20Minore%20Riformato%20e%20Missionario%20Apostolico%20del%20Ritiro%20di%20San%20Bonaventura%20in%20Roma%2C&f=false) the proof can indeed be found on p. 146, where begins---

"Del Poco Numero Degli Eletti" (Of the Little Number of Elect).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.